# Animated printer paper panetrating in each other

Tags: unity-game-engine

On GUI click

1. I am making a clone of animated print paper object
2. change its texture then
3. i play its animation.

All clone working fine, animate on button click perfectly but the problem is each time animation play, object penetrate in each other as the animation location is same. please see texture below

[image]

I have attached box collider and rigidbody to animated print paper object with no gravity and is kinematic true. How can I avoid it that animation play from same location but if the clone object already available there paper s**hould NOT penetrated** into another paper.

Comment: Its not clear what do you want. papers should be penetrated, or they should NOT be penetrated?

Comment: Animation does not care about physics. Whether you add a rigidbody and collider and whatnots will not change the result. This is because animations overwrites the whole data with what it contains.

Comment: I would keep the other paper object a bit off the position until the animation starts.

Comment: @UmairM sorry not penetrate

Comment: @Everts i have ten clone object

Comment: @Everts "Animation does not care about physics." Proof/ref?

Comment: Are you using Unity's animation system?

Comment: I had a similar case with an animated sword. Collision was just ignored. Was in Unity 3 tho...